# How to loop through a list of tikzpicture within animateinline?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, foreach, animate

I have the following code which uses `animateinline` and several `tikzpicture` for it's animation effects:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\def\layera{
  \path[cm={{0.8028232,-0.59621716,0.59621716,0.8028232,(0.0,0.0)}},draw=black,opacity=0.990,miter
    limit=4.00,line width=0.943pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (-99.8372,584.6912)
    rectangle (-30.7483,653.7801);
}

\def\layerb{
    \fill[blue!40] (0,0) circle (1);
}

\def\layerc{
    \fill[red!40] (0,0) circle (1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,controls]{1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \layera{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newframe
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \layerb{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newframe
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \layerc{}
\end{tikzpicture}

\newcommand{\makelayer}{
    \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
        \layerc{}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%\makelayer{}

%\def\MyLayers{\layerb, \layerc}
%\foreach \mylayer in \MyLayers {
%    \newframe
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
%        \mylayer{}
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%}

\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, it has 3 layers (1 layer/frame): layera, layerb and layerc. The following file could be converted to pdf and the animation effects are correct: a square, then a blue circle, and a red circle.

However, when I try to use `\newcommand` makelayer, the output is not correct: just uncomment `\makelayer{}` and compile to pdf. The strange thing is layerb is not shown correctly, instead of layerc, which is inside `\makelayer{}`?

It must be something obvious for a trained eye; could someone kindly point out what is the correct way of using `\newcommand` in this case?

The second question is looping through all the tikzpictures, and I think it might be related to the above question. I have also have the code that's not working commented out, starting at: `%\def\MyLayers{\layerb, \layerc}`

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit1**

@Harish's answer solved the first question.

To clarify my second question, which is how to loop through the contents of each `tikzpicture` using `foreach` or any other looping mechanism? I made some changes to the code to illustrate the question (the actual tex file may contain many more layers/`tikzpicture` ):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\newcommand\layera{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[cm={{0.8028232,-0.59621716,0.59621716,0.8028232,(0.0,0.0)}},draw=black,opacity=0.990,miter
    limit=4.00,line width=0.943pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (-99.8372,584.6912)
    rectangle (-30.7483,653.7801);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\layerb{%
    \fill[blue!40] (0,0) circle (1);
}

\newcommand\layerc{%
    \fill[red!40] (0,0) circle (1);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,controls]{1}
    \layera

\newcommand{\makemylayer}{%
    \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
        \layerb
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \newframe
    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]   
        \layerc
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\makemylayer

%\newcommand\MyLayers{\layerb, \layerc}
%\foreach \mylayer in \MyLayers {
%    \newframe
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
%        \mylayer{}
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%}


\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

There are 3 layers (`tikzpicture`): layera, layerb, and layerc, and except for layera, I'd like to loop through the contents of each `tikzpicture` (layerb and layerc).

So when I comment out `\makemylayer`, uncomment the `foreach` block, when I try to compile, there's the following error message:

```
! Package animate Error: Contents of first frame must not have zero width.
```

Thanks for your help.

**Edit2**

I've tried other looping methods such as `loop`, `forloop` etc., but most of them deals with a counter or something like that; could someone kindly provide any advice on how to iterate through the above list of commands and make it work?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Your first problem will be solved by putting a `%` after `\newcommand{\makelayer}{`.

And I think I didn't get your second question properly. It can be done as shown in this modified code of yours.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\newcommand\layera{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \path[cm={{0.8028232,-0.59621716,0.59621716,0.8028232,(0.0,0.0)}},draw=black,opacity=0.990,miter
    limit=4.00,line width=0.943pt,rounded corners=0.0000cm] (-99.8372,584.6912)
    rectangle (-30.7483,653.7801);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\layerb{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \fill[blue!40] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand\layerc{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
    \fill[red!40] (0,0) circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[loop,controls]{1}
    \layera
\newframe
    \layerb
\newframe
    \layerc

\newcommand{\makelayer}{%
    \newframe
        \layerb
}

\makelayer

%\def\MyLayers{\layerb, \layerc}
%\foreach \mylayer in \MyLayers {
%    \newframe
%    \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt,x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
%        \mylayer{}
%    \end{tikzpicture}
%}

%% Instead of above try this:

\newcommand{\makemylayer}{%
    \newframe
        \layera
    \newframe
        \layerc
    \newframe
         \layerb
}

\makemylayer

\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have changed the order of appearance to make things clear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `\newcommand{\makelayer}{%` makes the `\makelayer` work.